# __dopostback not working code C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater like that:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1"  runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptstudent" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
      <table id="table1">
         <tr class="repeater_bg">
             <th width="40px">order</th>
             <th width="300px">Name</th>
             <th width="300px">Card</th>
        </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="repeater_item">
            <td align="center">
                <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="Id" Value='<%# Eval("IdStudent") %>' runat="server" />
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </td>
             <td align="center">
                <%# Eval("IdStudent") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Label ID="lblPagination" CssClass="pagination" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

view source code:

```
order     name                                         Card
1         Alex (hidden field value is idstudent=1)     1
2         Alex2 (hidden field value is idstudent=2)    2
3         Alex3 (hidden field value is idstudent=3)    4
4         Alex4 (hidden field value is idstudent=4)    3
5         Alex5 (hidden field value is idstudent=5)    5

                             first page 1 2 3 4 last page
```

and a label for paging(binding value using code behind), all of them nested rad ajax panel.
Now when i click on the link to go to page 2

```
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('page0','0')">First Page</a></li>
<li><a id="page1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('page1','1')">1</a></li>
<li><a id="page2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('page2','2')">2</a></li>
<li><a style="font-size:8pt;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('page2','2')">Last Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

is works, the data is transferred to the 2nd page. but when I see the source code of the page, hidden field in repeater is not reload data. Card and name is corect
view source code:

```
order     name                                                             Card
6         Alex6 (hidden field value remains constant =1, must be 6)         6
7         Alex7 (hidden field value remains constant =2, must be 7)         7
8         Alex8 (hidden field value remains constant =3, must be 8)         8
9         Alex8 (hidden field value remains constant =4, must be 9)         9
10        Alex8 (hidden field value remains constant =5, must be 10)        10
                                                         first page 1 2 3 4 last page
```

code behind

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{

}
else
{
// when you click a link, it's called event __dopostback
   string postBackControlName = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
   string eventArgument = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");
   if (postBackControlName == "page"+eventArgument)
   {
      LoadData(int.Parse(eventArgument));
   }
}
```

Why this is happening, is there any way to solve this.

Thank for advance
Sory about my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
if (!isPostBack)
{
    //do something
}

else if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToLower().IndexOf("myevent") >= 0)
{
    //call appropriate function.
}
```

Check if you are getting a call this way

Comment: thanks for your comment. It is not working, i can call page 2, but hidden field is not change value. i using rad ajax panel nested all of them

Comment: Then try this way on code behind   liID.Attribute.Add("onclick","__doPosback("+page2.UniqueID+")")